# cd not working as intended in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, cron, cd

Er.. There is a question with almost the same title on stackoverflow, but there is a difference in my question. My code is this

```
cd /oracle_data/indata/VXMLIVR
ls -d SMSR > temporary4.txt
while read smsr_line;do echo $smsr_line;cd $smsr_line;./smsr_alarm;cd ..;done < temporary4.txt
ls -d SMSC > temporary3.txt
while read smsc_line;do echo $smsc_line;cd $smsc_line;./smsc_alarm;cd ..;done < temporary3.txt
ls -d HCIVR5 > temporary.txt
while read hcivr_line;do echo $hcivr_line;cd $hcivr_line;./hcivr_alarm;cd ..;done < temporary.txt
ls -d HCIVR6 > temporary.txt
while read hcivr_line;do echo $hcivr_line;cd $hcivr_line;./hcivr_alarm;cd ..;done < temporary.txt
ls -d HCIVR7 > temporary.txt
while read hcivr_line;do echo $hcivr_line;cd $hcivr_line;./hcivr_alarm;cd ..;done < temporary.txt
ls -d HCIVR8 > temporary.txt
while read hcivr_line;do echo $hcivr_line;cd $hcivr_line;./hcivr_alarm;cd ..;done < temporary.txt
ls -d IVR* > temporary2.txt
while read ivr_line;do echo $ivr_line;cd $ivr_line;./ivr_alarm;cd ..;done < temporary2.txt
rm temp*
```

I have saved this script as vas_alarm. when i remove the first line(cd /oracle_data/indata/VXMLIVR), manually do cd /oracle_data/indata/VXMLIVR and run ./vas_alarms everything works fine. But when i run the entire script like this:

```
oracle@sunv440$/oracle_data/indata/VXMLIVR/vas_alarms
: No such file or directory/vas_alarms: line 1: cd: /oracle_data/indata/VXMLIVR
```

im getting an error. Where am i going wrong? The thing is my script is saved in /oracle_data/indata/VXMLIVR and i need to run it after entering this location. Also the script has to be saved in a cron file. Any workarounds will also do. My main aim is to schedule /oracle_data/indata/VXMLIVR/vas_alarms

Comment: Looks like you've got funky chars in your file. Try passing it through `hexdump -C` to see if you can spot anything strange (or `od -x`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you have some invisible characters in your file.

For example:

```
$ touch hello

$ echo $'\rhello'
hello

$ ls $'\rhello'
hello: No such file or directory
```

You can use `xxd`/`hexdump`/`od` to view the binary presentation:

```
$ echo $'\rhello' | xxd
0000000: 0d68 656c 6c6f 0a                        .hello.
```

`xxd` will print all unprintable charactors as `.`s(dots).
Notice that these's a `.`(dot) at the beginning.

Comment: yea incorrect characters were there ^M. Opened using vi and fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a few comments, but since the comment facility doesn't have support for code snippets, I'm posting this as an answer.

Your code could really use some refactoring.  You should avoid repetitive code, and you should avoid temporary files.  You should avoid parsing the output of `ls`.  You are sometimes overwriting the temporary file, and sometimes not.

`cd ..` is somewhat brittle when symlinks are involved.  A common idiom is to do `cd` in a subshell, which will cause the parent shell to remain in the current directory.

So here then is my attempt at refactoring;

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /oracle_data/indata/VMXLIVR

while read cmd dirs; do
    for dir in $dirs; do
        for subdir in $dir/*/.; do
            echo "$subdir"
            ( cd "$subdir"; ./"$cmd"; )
        done
    done
done <<HERE
    smsr_alarm  SMSR
    smsc_alarm  SMSC
    hcivr_alarm HCIVR[5678] 
    ivr_alarm   IVR*        
HERE
```

This will break if some of the subdirectories contain whitespace in their names.  I am making some assumptions about the directory structure which are implied but not clearly demonstrated in your text.